# stripping space between string in convert to list

Tags: string, python-2.7

I have a string - data is read from *.txt

```
21 197 251 251 253 107 0 0 0 0 0
```

want to convert to the list as follows :

```
[21.0, 197.0, 251.0, 251.0, 253.0, 107.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

wrote this function and tried options #1, #2, and #3

```
def loadCsv(filename):
    lines = csv.reader(open(filename, "rb"))
    dataset = list(lines)
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        #1 dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
        #2 dataset[i] = [map(float, x.strip()) for x in dataset[i]]
        #3 dataset[i]=[map(float, x.split()) for x in dataset[i]]
    return datase
```

When I use:

1. the string obviously cannot be converted to float,

> Error I receive ValueError: invalid literal for float()

2. I thought there is a space between the elements that's causing it.

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: there is space that is
>   causing that error

3. When I map string to float using this, it works on this function, but then when I call the data to categorize, it renders

> unhashable list error

```
def separateByClass(dataset):
    separated = {}
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        vector = dataset[i]
        if (vector[-1] not in separated):
            separated[vector[-1]] = []
        separated[vector[-1]].append(vector)
    return separated
```

Any thoughts?

---

> I am updating loadCsv function as below which resolved the issue:

---

```
def loadCsv(filename):
    lines = open(filename)
    lines=lines.read()
    dataset = list(lines.split())#list(lines)

    for i in range(len(dataset)):

        #dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
        #dataset[i]=[map(float, x.strip()) for x in dataset[i]]
        dataset[i]=[float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
    return dataset
```

Comment: Are all those number on the same line or on separate lines?

Comment: Its one row out of multiple in the txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dataset` list is the list of lines in the file, but your numbers are all in one line and separated by spaces. You have to `split` the line and convert the segments to `float`.

Your last line `[map(float, x.split()) for x in dataset[i]]` is close, but if `dataset[i]` is a line, then `x` is a character, i.e. you are iterating over characters in the line and split *those*.

You can use either `map`...

```
>>> line = "21 197 251 251 253 107 0 0 0 0 0"
>>> list(map(float, line.split()))
[21.0, 197.0, 251.0, 251.0, 253.0, 107.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

... or a list comprehension:

```
>>> [float(x) for x in line.split()]
[21.0, 197.0, 251.0, 251.0, 253.0, 107.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Combine this with reading from file (no need for `csv`):

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()
    data = list(map(float, text.split()))
```

ABout the not-hashable-problem: The result is a list, which can not be put in a `set` or (as a key) in a `dict`. For this, you'd have to convert the `list` to a `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `splitlines()` and a list comprehension:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        r = [float(item) for line in f.read().splitlines() for item in line.split(" ")]
        print (r)
```